# Javascript - copying elements to the object's array with callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

```js
let client1 = {
  accounts: Array(),
  accounts_setter: function(obtained_accounts) {
      i = obtained_accounts.length;
      this.accounts = obtained_accounts.slice();
    }
}

function generateAndPushElements(callback) {
 var toPassAccounts =  ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 callback(toPassAccounts);
}

generateAndPushElements(client1.accounts_setter);
console.log(client1.accounts);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Following code does not fill an object's array, but the process of doing it is in my opinion correct. Do

But the scope is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have here is that `this` isn't the right context in your callback. You're not setting the property of `client1`.

You can fix it with

```
generateAndPushElements(client1.accounts_setter.bind(client1));
```

for example.

Be careful if you use this construct in real code with an asynchronous function: your `console.log` would be misplaced as it logs before any asynchronous task returns.

Comment: @Denys Seguret , we can use arrow functions here isn't